# detect both hyphens and spaces from input in python?

Tags: python

I am creating a simple script to practice python; It will count chars in name also detect hyphens and spaces; but I have a problem
**Example code:**

```
text = input('enter hyphen and space:')
if '-' in text:
    print('hyphen in text')
elif ' ' in text:
    print('space in text')
elif ' ' and '-' in text:
    print('hyphen and space in text')
else:
    print('Nothing :( ')
```

When the user write both space and hyphens in text , it says `hyphen in text`
How can I prevent this?
**Main code:**

```
name = input('Enter your name:')
from time import sleep
if ' ' in name:
    print('Looks like your name contain spaces')
    sleep(0.6)
    op1 = input('Count spaces in it? y/n\n')
    sleep(0.6)
    if op1.lower() == 'y':
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
    if op1.lower() != 'y':
        name = name.replace(' ','')
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
elif '-' in name:
    print('Looks like your name contain hyphens ( - )')
    sleep(0.6)
    op = input('Count hyphens in it? y/n\n')
    sleep(0.6)
    if op.lower() == 'y':
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
    if op.lower() != 'y':
        name = name.replace('-','')
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
if '-' and ' ' in name:
    print('Looks like your name contain both hyphen/s and space/s')
    sleep(0.6)
    print('options:\n')
    sleep(0.8)
    print('1) Count hyphen/s')
    print('2) Count space/s')
    print('3) Count both')
    print('4) Skip both')
    sleep(1)
    op = input('1 / 2 / 3 \nEnter your choice:')
    op = op.lower()
    sleep(0.6)
    if op == '1':
        name = name.replace(' ','')
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
    if op == '2':
        name = name.replace('-','')
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
    if op == '3':
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
    if op == '4':
        name = name.replace('-','')
        name = name.replace(' ','')
        name = len(name)
        print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
else:
    name = len(name)
    print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
```

Comment: Just test if both space and hyphen in text first. I.e. if space and hyphen, else if space, else if hyphen.

Comment: If I test `if '-' and ' ' in text` only , it say `hyphen and space in text`

Comment: See @AzatIbrakov's answer below.

Comment: why are you doing `name = len(name)` in your main snippet? it may cause some undesired behavior, you should name things after what they are (e.g . `name_length` in this case)

Comment: I think its ok because I replaced it to digits whatever it was before.

Comment: you should bear in mind that it may (and will) break your code sooner or later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set complex condition at the top, also do not forget to duplicate check `in text` because

```
' ' and '-' in text
```

will be `True` if there is only hyphen in `text` since `' '` is a `True`-like string, you should do:

```
' ' in text and '-' in text
```

finally we can have something like

```
if ' ' in text and '-' in text:
    print('hyphen and space in text')
elif '-' in text:
    print('hyphen in text')
elif ' ' in text:
    print('space in text')
else:
    print('Nothing :( ')
```

Answer (score 2):

When your input flows into the if-statement, the first condition is checked. That condition is `'-' in text` which will evaluate to `True` if `text = "- "` and then exit the if-statement. What we are looking for is to check for the most specific case first, that is `' ' and '-' in text`. So the correct program would look something like this:

```
text = input('enter hyphen and space:')
if ' ' in text and '-' in text:
    print('hyphen and space in text')
elif '-' in text:
    print('hyphen in text')
elif ' ' in text:
    print('space in text')
else:
    print('Nothing :( ')
```

Comment: your first statement should be `if ' ' in text and '-' in text`

Answer (score 1):

Order of your conditional statements is the problem here, since it would always get into the first if, ie `if '-' in text` as in your example case both hyphen and space is there. Also since the condition to check for both these cases is in `elif` it will never be executed.

So you have to have your condition, 
`" " and "_" in text` at the first.

Always remember if , elif(optional) , else works in sequential order and also only one part of the block gets executed based on your condition.

Note : your code will throw an error if any non string input is given like an integer. So I have added `raw_input`, You can always use this typecast it to your desired datatype or even use exception handling for the same.

So your actual code should be like this,

> ```
> name = raw_input('Enter your name:')
> from time import sleep
> if '-' and ' ' in name:
>     print('Looks like your name contain both hyphen/s and space/s')
>     sleep(0.6)
>     print('options:\n')
>     sleep(0.8)
>     print('1) Count hyphen/s')
>     print('2) Count space/s')
>     print('3) Count both')
>     print('4) Skip both')
>     sleep(1)
>     op = input('1 / 2 / 3 \nEnter your choice:')
>     op = op.lower()
>     sleep(0.6)
>     if op == '1':
>         name = name.replace(' ','')
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
>     if op == '2':
>         name = name.replace('-','')
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
>     if op == '3':
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
>     if op == '4':
>         name = name.replace('-','')
>         name = name.replace(' ','')
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
> elif ' ' in name:
>     print('Looks like your name contain spaces')
>     sleep(0.6)
>     op1 = input('Count spaces in it? y/n\n')
>     sleep(0.6)
>     if op1.lower() == 'y':
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
>     if op1.lower() != 'y':
>         name = name.replace(' ','')
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
> elif '-' in name:
>     print('Looks like your name contain hyphens ( - )')
>     sleep(0.6)
>     op = input('Count hyphens in it? y/n\n')
>     sleep(0.6)
>     if op.lower() == 'y':
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
>     if op.lower() != 'y':
>         name = name.replace('-','')
>         name = len(name)
>         print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
>
> else:
>     name = len(name)
>     print('Numbers in your name: ',name)
> ```